# Problem with reindexing with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, bundle, searchkick

I can't seem to re-index Elasticsearch, I am getting error mapper_parsing_exception when I run `bundle exec rake searchkick:reindex:all`

Everything went fine, then I changed branch on git to an older version, now the indexing seems wrong.

> DEPRECATION WARNING: The factory_girl gem is deprecated. Please
>   upgrade to factory_bot. See
>   https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/v4.9.0/UPGRADE_FROM_FACTORY_GIRL.md
>   for further instructions. (called from  at
>   /home/sid/Documents/meew-companies/meew-companies-dashboard/config/application.rb:8)
>   ** Invoke searchkick:reindex:all (first_time)
>   ** Invoke environment (first_time)
>   ** Execute environment
>   ** Execute searchkick:reindex:all Reindexing Job... rake aborted! Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400]
>   {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root
>   mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [job : {_routing={},
>   dynamic_templates=[{string_template={mapping={ignore_above=30000,
>   type=keyword,
>   fields={word_start={analyzer=searchkick_word_start_index, index=true,
>   type=text}}}, match_mapping_type=string, match=*}}],
>   properties={location={type=geo_point}}}]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed
>   to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported
>   parameters:  [job : {_routing={},
>   dynamic_templates=[{string_template={mapping={ignore_above=30000,
>   type=keyword,
>   fields={word_start={analyzer=searchkick_word_start_index, index=true,
>   type=text}}}, match_mapping_type=string, match=*}}],
>   properties={location={type=geo_point}}}]","caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root
>   mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [job : {_routing={},
>   dynamic_templates=[{string_template={mapping={ignore_above=30000,
>   type=keyword,
>   fields={word_start={analyzer=searchkick_word_start_index, index=true,
>   type=text}}}, match_mapping_type=string, match=*}}],
>   properties={location={type=geo_point}}}]"}},"status":400}

Comment: The reason is that you're using a searchkick version that is not compatible with your ES version (or vice versa). Please add the versions you're using.

Comment: solved it. for some reason rake db:setup had to be done. some problems I don't know why